# Subscript a title in a Graph (ggplot2) with label of another file

Tags: r, linux, loops, ggplot2, command

In my program I have two main files, the first with the data and the second with labels (or titles of my graphics):

File total1 (data)

```
3   10000   3   32039232    1   0.0017290351    2   0.0002781092
3   10001   3   32101193    1   0.0045398899    2   0.0032875689
3   1000    1   60233253    1   0.0022057964    2   6.747e-06
3   10002   3   32108182    1   0.0219913914    2   0.0102120679
3   10003   3   32133994    1   0.0007025013    2   0.0010197563
3   10004   3   32192498    1   0.0029210855    2   0.0036980008
3   10005   3   32230041    1   0.0005408603    2   0.0015782048
3   10006   3   32271305    1   1.099e-07       2   0.0033466856
3   10007   3   32289336    1   0.0185812303    2   0.0027349589
3   10008   3   32453784    1   0.0080117379    2   0.0003596759
```

File leg (labels)

```
Áre de olho de lombo
Espessura de gordura subcutânea
pH0 inicial 
pH24 final
Perda por cocção
Força de cisalhamento
Cor L*
Cor a*
Cor b*
```

I am using linux commands and R simultaneously on the same bash card, to plot graphs. I'm doing looping in this script:

> ## !/bin/bash
>
> for l in {1..9};  do
>
> R -q -e "leg<-read.table('leg',
>   header=F,sep='\t');write.table(leg,'lef1.txt', sep='\t', row.names =
>   F,col.names=F);uni$l<-read.table('./var/chrsnpvar_uni$l',header=F);bi$l<-read.table('./var/chrsnpvar_bi$l',
>   header=F); map<-read.table('snp_map_clean',sep='\t',header =
>   F);uni1$l=uni$l[ which(uni$l[,1]==1 & uni$l[,2]==3), ]; bi1$l=bi$l [
>   which(bi$l[,1]==2 & bi$l[,2]==3), ];total$l <- merge(uni1$l,bi1$l,
>   by=c(2,4,5,6), all=T);write.table(total$l,'total$l.txt', sep='\t',
>   row.names =
>   F,col.names=F);library(ggplot2);tiff('./solution/cor$l.tiff', width
>   =10 , height = 6, units = 'in',res = 75 ); ggplot(total$l,aes(x=total$l[,6], y=total$l[,8])) + geom_point() +
>   scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(0), max(0.08), by =
>   0.01),2),limits=c(0,0.08))+ scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(0), max(0.08), by = 0.01),2),limits=c(0,0.08)) +
>   geom_smooth(method=lm , color='grey35', se=FALSE)+
>   geom_vline(xintercept =
>   quantile(total$l[,6],0.95),lty=2,size=1,colour='grey')+ 
>   geom_hline(yintercept = quantile(total$l[,8], .95),
>   lty=2,size=1,colour='grey') + ylab('Bicaracterística') +
>   xlab('Unicaracterística')+ theme_classic()+
>   theme(axis.line.x=element_line(colour='black',size=1),axis.line.y=element_line(colour='black',size=1),
>   axis.ticks.length= unit(4,'mm'),legend.title =
>   element_blank(),axis.title.y = element_text(size = 22), axis.title.x =
>   element_text(size = 22),axis.text.x=element_text(size =
>   22),axis.text.y=element_text(size = 22), legend.text=element_text(size
>   = 22), title=element_text(size =22)) + annotate('text', x = 0.005, y=0.07, label = 'A',size=8) + annotate('text', x = 0.06, y=0.07, label
>   = 'B',size=8)+ annotate('text', x = 0.005, y=0.005, label = 'C', colour='white', size=8)+ annotate('text', x = 0.06, y=0.005, label =
>   'D',size=8)+ggtitle(leg[$l,1]); dev.off()"
>
> done

The program is ok, I just need to write the 24 of "pH24 final" and 0 of "pH0 Inicial" in subscript form in my graphic titles, to write the titles from the label file I am using the command`ggtitle(leg[$l,1])`. Does anyone know how I can do this by using the label of another file?

Comment: I would personally do the loop in R rather than invoking R from bash for each file

Comment: This is a part of my program. And somethings only bash do. But I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7):

See if this can give you some idea. Using math expression in base R seems to work for ggplot titles.

```
library(ggplot2)

df=data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10))

vn=expression(paste(pH[10]," inicial"))
ggplot(df, aes(x,y))+geom_point()+ ggtitle(vn)
```

[image]