# Is there a way to self-identify a list element's name within purrr/lapply?

Tags: r, purrr

I want to pull the name of a list element out as the text for a plot title within an `lapply()` or `map()` function.

The point is to self-identify a list elements name within the lapply or map call, rather then supply them as an additional argument. My real use case already has other arguments going into the function, and I am curious if there is a way around doing that because it would simplify things quite a bit.

Self Identify a list element within purrr::map or lapply
Say I have a list

```
library(tidyverse)
my_list <- list(A = data.frame(level = factor(1:5),
                               value = rnorm(5)),
                B = data.frame(level = factor(1:5),
                               value = rnorm(5)))
```

And a simple function to plot it

```
test_fun <- function(named_list) {
  ggplot(named_list) +
    geom_col(aes(level, value)) +
    ggtitle(named_list)
}
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
purrr::map(my_list, test_fun)
```

...But have them titled "A" & "B".

The goal is to identify the name of elements "A" or "B" within map/lapply
That way I can pass that name as the plot title without supplying them as another function argument.

I've tried these within the function:

```
names(named_list)
# &
attr(named_list, "name")
```

But they each will pull the names within element A or B, which is not the desired behavior. I want to be up one level.

I know that I could pass the names as a separate object with map2

```
my_names <- names(my_list)
test_fun2 <- function(named_list, my_names) {
  ggplot(named_list) +
    geom_col(aes(level, value)) +
    ggtitle(my_names)
}
```

Then do this:

```
map2(my_list, my_names, test_fun2)
```

But is there a way to just insert the list element name instead of doing that? If there isn't that is fine, I am curious whether a way exists or if I'm stuck supplying the names.

## EDIT: Looking for clarity on `imap()` answer:

I can get the `imap()` suggestions to work on my simple example but only with an anonymous function. If I could get some clarity on the below example I should be able to scale up to the more complicated use.

### Why does this fail

```
test_fun_imap <- function(named_list) {
  ggplot(.x) +
    geom_col(aes(level, value)) +
    ggtitle(.y)
}

imap(my_list, test_fun_imap)
```

### But this works

```
imap(my_list, ~{
  ggplot(.x) +
    geom_col(aes(level, value)) +
    ggtitle(.y)
}
)
```

Comment: See `purrr::imap` or `purrr::map2`.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how imap would work in this instance? I know map2 can be used, but as mentioned in the question I'm curious if I can circumvent that option.

Comment: @adamkemberling: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55114232/786542

Comment: You shouldn't change your question to ask a new question in an "edit." If this answer raises a new question for you, you should start a new post.

Comment: @MrFlick I agree with your point, and won't do that in the future. In this case though its still an extension of the original question. I will do better though moving forward, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @joran you can use `imap` but for that you need to pass two arguments to the function for it to work

```
test_fun_imap <- function(x, y) {
   ggplot(x) +
    geom_col(aes(level, value)) +
    ggtitle(y)
}
```

and then you can call

```
purr::imap(my_list, test_fun_imap)
```

---

As far as knowing why it will not work with `map` or `lapply`, you can debug the function by adding `browser()` in the function

```
test_fun <- function(named_list) {
   browser()
  ggplot(named_list) +
    geom_col(aes(level, value)) +
    ggtitle(named_list)
}
```

Now, call it using `map`

```
purrr::map(my_list, test_fun)
```

Check what is passed as parameter `named_list`

```
Called from: .f(.x[[i]], ...)
Browse[1]> named_list
#  level    value
#1     1 -1.20707
#2     2  0.27743
#3     3  1.08444
#4     4 -2.34570
#5     5  0.42912
```

You see that the dataframe is passed and there is no information of name of that list (`"A"`) hence, it is not possible to use that as title of the plot. As you already know you can use `map2` or `mapply` for that passing the name of the list separately.